# How to specify a lamdba function in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, function, lambda

I am trying to understand the usage of lambda functions in VB.NET, using the following example. But something is not correct.  Specifying 'Dim t as string = ...' doesn't work either. Can this be done?

```
Dim tagsList As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Dim Name as string = "abc"
Dim t = Function(aName As String) If(tagsList.ContainsKey(aName), tagsList(aName), Nothing)
Dim Tag as string = t(Name)
```

Error   BC30209 Option Strict On requires all variable declarations to have an 'As' clause.
Error   BC30574 Option Strict On disallows late binding.

Comment: I think you have to make it a Delegate, like Dim t as Del = Function ... See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc36642

Comment: Dim IsBob As String = If(Name = "Bob", "It's Bob!", "Not Bob")

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick.

Comment: I know linking out isn't preferred here but this article helped me out a lot with Lambda's: [https://www.codemag.com/article/1001051/Practical-Uses-of-Lambdas](https://www.codemag.com/article/1001051/Practical-Uses-of-Lambdas)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the errors, it appears that you have `Option Infer Off`.

I'd recommend to turn `Option Infer On`, then your code will work exactly as presented.  I can't really think of a good reason to ever have inference off.

Without type inference, you must declare the type of `t`.  As noted in the comments, you can declare `t` to be `[Delegate]`, but then you'll also have a problem at the point where you try to call.  In order to get it to compile, I needed to change the right hand side to `Cstr(t.DynamicInvoke(name))`.  A better alternative, if you're going this route, is to declare the delegate type explicitly (which must be done at class/module level), e.g.

```
Delegate Function RetrieveTag(ByVal name As String) As String
```

Then you declare `t` as having this type, e.g.

```
Dim t As RetrieveTag = ...
```